# Get data from another Database in Codeigniter MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to get data from another DB in MySQL except the defualt DB. I added the following line into my model in addition to the excisting code. Another DB as 'storesDB'.

```
$this->load->database('storesDB', TRUE);
```

My model as follows :

```
public function getEquipment($id = null)
    {  
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_equipment');
        $this->db->join('tbl_equipment_category', 'tbl_equipment.eq_cat=tbl_equipment_category.id_cat');
        $this->db->where("tbl_equipment.status", '1');
        if ($id)
            $this->db->where("tbl_equipment.id", $id);        
            $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

The code is working properly. But the code got data from defualt DB not the by the 'storesDB'.

Modified code is as follows :

```
public function getEquipment($id = null)
    {       
        $this->load->database('storesDB', TRUE);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_equipment');
        $this->db->join('tbl_equipment_category', 'tbl_equipment.eq_cat=tbl_equipment_category.id_cat');
        $this->db->where("tbl_equipment.status", '1');
        if ($id)
            $this->db->where("tbl_equipment.id", $id);        
            $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

What may be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you don't assign the second database properly. You also need to setup the correct config for the 2nd database

```
$config['hostname'] = "host";
$config['username'] = "user";
$config['password'] = "pass";
$config['database'] = "storesDB";
// etc..
```

then you load the database:

```
$this->db2 = load->database($config, TRUE);
```

now you have `$this->db`, the default database and `$this->db2`, the second database

and continue your code like:

```
$this->db2->select('*');
$this->db2->from('tbl_equipment');
// etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience in Codeigniter, but in a standar sql query you can add the database name in front of the table to get info from another db like:

SELECT * FROM sakila.actor;

Assuming you are not connected to sakila db.

Using this aproach both databases must have same credentials